# Why does my query take so long and how can I optimize it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am trying to combine the results of all these separated (sub) queries into one single result. I have really basic knowledge of SQL.

I am able to get a result, but it takes a massive 6 seconds.

Edit:
Query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJvCySy12

[image]

What can I do with my query to make it much much faster?

```
   WITH t AS (
    SELECT DateTime,Value,wwUnit 
    FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
    WHERE TagName = 'N_AC001_01_AC_470_01.Data_2' 
        AND DateTime >= '2/15/2023 10:11:37 AM' 
        AND DateTime <= '3/1/2023 10:11:37 AM' 
        AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'  
        AND wwQualityRule='optimistic'
),
min_max_avg AS (
    SELECT  
        Min(Value) AS MIN,
        Max(Value) AS MAX,
        AVG(Value) AS AVERAGE, 
        STDEV(Value) AS STD_DEV 
    FROM t
),
eng_unit AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 wwUnit 
    FROM t  
),
min_value_time AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 DateTime TIME_AT_MIN
    FROM t 
    WHERE Value = (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM t)
),
max_value_time AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 DateTime AS TIME_AT_MAX
    FROM t 
    WHERE Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM t)
),
first_logged_value AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 Datetime as START_RANGE
    FROM t
),
last_logged_value AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 DateTime AS END_RANGE 
    FROM t 
    ORDER BY DateTime DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM min_max_avg, eng_unit, min_value_time, max_value_time, first_logged_value, last_logged_value;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan (an option within SSMS, it's Ctrl+M on some versions but search if you don't spot it easily)? What steps are taking the most time? Do you have indexes that support the expensive steps? If you put comments on your code describing the execution plan cost and the indexes used for each sub-query we might help you better.

Comment: Enable actual query plan and use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share it here so we can look at the actual bottleneck.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Peter https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJvCySy12      here you go :)

Comment: While we can only offer performance advice after seeing the execution plan, given how complex this query is you might benefit from storing some of the intermediate results in a temp table to split the execution plan up, then SQL Server can optimise each section better.

Comment: It looks like most of the time is in retrieving the data from a linked server. I suggest you set those values in a temp table, then you can use that a a base to retrieve the other information.

Comment: @DaleK Not sure why this needs a temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DateTime,Value,wwUnit,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value ASC) AS min_value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) AS max_value
INTO #temp
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
WHERE TagName = 'N_AC001_01_AC_470_01.Data_2' 
    AND DateTime >= '2/15/2023 10:11:37 AM' 
    AND DateTime <= '3/1/2023 10:11:37 AM' 
    AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'  
    AND wwQualityRule='optimistic'

SELECT Min(Value) AS MIN,
       Max(Value) AS MAX,
       AVG(Value) AS AVERAGE, 
       STDEV(Value) AS STD_DEV,
       Max(wwUnit) AS wwUnit,
       --
       MIN(CASE WHEN min_value = 1 THEN DateTime END) AS TIME_AT_MIN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN max_value = 1 THEN DateTime END) AS TIME_AT_MAX,
       --
       Min(Datetime) AS first_logged_value,
       Max(Datetime) AS last_logged_value
FROM #temp;
```

The idea is save the needed data in temporary table. At the same time, mark the rows with min and max values. Then in later query calculated all the needed values without sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of efficiencies you can make:

- You can use window functions to remove the need for subqueries.
- You can combine all of them into a single query scope, no need for joins.
- Always use a non-ambiguous date format.

The other answer also has some efficiency issues:

- The temp table is not needed, you can do it one query.
- Row numbering in opposite directions is inefficient. We can use `LEAD` instead for the opposing direction, in order to keep the sorting the same.

```sql
SELECT
  MIN(h.Value) AS MIN,
  MAX(h.Value) AS MAX,
  AVG(h.Value) AS AVERAGE, 
  STDEV(h.Value) AS STD_DEV, 
  MIN(CASE WHEN h.rn = 1 THEN h.wwUnit END) AS wwUnit,
  MIN(CASE WHEN h.rn = 1 THEN h.DateTime END) AS TIME_AT_MIN,
  MIN(CASE WHEN h.NextValue IS NULL THEN h.DateTime END) AS TIME_AT_MAX,
  MIN(h.Datetime) AS START_RANGE,
  MAX(h.Datetime) AS END_RANGE
FROM (
    SELECT
      h.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY h.Value) AS rn,
      LEAD(h.Value) OVER (ORDER BY h.Value) AS NextValue
    FROM dbo.History h
    WHERE TagName = 'N_AC001_01_AC_470_01.Data_2' 
        AND h.DateTime >= '2023-02-15 10:11:37' 
        AND h.DateTime <= '2023-03-01 10:11:37'
        AND h.wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'  
        AND h.wwQualityRule = 'optimistic'
) h;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, using your query made the average execution time measured over 10 executions go down from 332 to 287